# Determine tablelayoutpanel item dropped into

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to determine which cell (row/column) of my TableLayoutPanel the user drops an object into. Currently I have only been able to find how to determine coordinates of where the item is dropped which is:

```
Dim location As Point = TableLayoutPanel1.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
```

However I can not figure out how to locate which cell that is in. I did find the command GetCellPosition and attempted that with the coordinates; however that did not work either.

```
TableLayoutPanel1.GetCellPosition(location)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this function:

```
Private Function GetCellFromPoint(p As Point) As Point
  Dim result As New Point(-1, -1)
  Dim colWidths As Integer() = tlp.GetColumnWidths()
  Dim rowHeights As Integer() = tlp.GetRowHeights()
  Dim top As Integer = 0
  For y As Integer = 0 To rowHeights.Length - 1
    Dim left As Integer = 0
    For x As Integer = 0 To colWidths.Length - 1
      If New Rectangle(left, top, colWidths(x), rowHeights(y)).Contains(p) Then
        result = New Point(x, y)
      End If
      left += colWidths(x)
    Next
    top += rowHeights(y)
  Next
  Return result
End Function
```

It just loops through the rows and columns to see if the passed in point is inside the existing cell.  Note though, that `GetColumnWidths` and `GetRowHeights` do not appear in the intellisense dropdown.

Usage:

```
Private Sub tlp_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) _
                          Handles tlp.MouseMove
  Me.Text = GetCellFromPoint(e.Location).ToString
End Sub
```

BTW, `GetCellPosition` is expecting a control to be passed as a parameter, not a Point structure.

You can also use `TableLayoutPanelCellPosition` in place of Point in this function, since that is what GetCellPosition is returning in its function.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this function (thanks a million) but I have found an issue. To define correctly the cell where the object is droped, we need to take into account the location of the TableLayoutPanel in the screen. I have solved this making the declaration of p (build with e.X and e.Y in the DragDrop event) and r (a reference of the location of the TableLayoutPanel in the screen).
Then you have to assing p = p - r and send that P to the function GetCellFromPoint(p).

```
Private Sub TableLayoutPanel1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel1.DragDrop
Dim p As New Point(e.X, e.Y)
Dim r As Point
r = TableLayoutPanel1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
p.X = p.X - r.X
p.Y = p.Y - r.Y
MessageBox.Show(GetCellFromPoint(p).ToString)
End Sub
```